# How to hook up UIPageControl so it scrolls up with other controls?

Tags: uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I places a UIScrollView inside the main UIView of my viewcontroller.

Then I added some controls at the bottom of the view and a UIPageControl near the top.

When i scroll the view, the bottom controls scroll fine but the UIPageControl remains in place, so it ends up blocking the buttons and labels at the bottom.

How do I make the UIPageControl and its views scroll up or down with the rest?

Here is what it looks like

[image: Storyboard Scene]

Comment: did you find a solution to the problem? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu to be honest I simply moved everything back up to make it fit. As you can see from the scene inspector, everything is inside the UIScrollView.

Comment: my page control is also inside scroll view but it's not scrolling. it's just staying where it is even though all the constraints are set correctly. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259275/uipagecontrol-doesnt-obey-its-constraints-inside-uiscrollview

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by:

1) Putting all views/controls inside a containerView and declaring it as a property.

2) Adding this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.containerView.bounds.size;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //added with containerview from g8productions
    self.containerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, 59, 900, 1200)];
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.containerView.bounds.size];
}
```

Now it scrolls! :)